# SQL: combining a total count along with a conditional count

Tags: sql, string, oracle, count, pivot

I would like to return the total number of rooms in a hotel, and also provide the total number of rooms in that hotel that have more than 2 bedrooms. My code returns the total number of rooms in each hotel that have more than 2 bedrooms, but it does not return the total number of rooms in the hotel. Instead, it only returns the total number of rooms that have more than 2 bedrooms.

Is there a simple way to modify my code to resolve this issue?

I have the following code:

```
SELECT
    hotel.hotel_id,
    hotel.hotel_name,
    COUNT(room.room_no) || ' total rooms ' || COUNT(room.room_no) 
    || ' have more than 2 bedrooms ' AS ACCOMODATION_AVAILABLE
FROM
    hotel
INNER JOIN
    room
ON
    hotel.hotel_id = room.hotel_id
WHERE
    room_bedrooms > 2
GROUP BY
    hotel.hotel_id, hotel.hotel_name;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT h.hotel_id, h.hotel_name,
       COUNT(*) as total_roms,
       SUM(CASE WHEN r.room_bedrooms > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_3plus
FROM hotel h JOIN
     room r
     ON h.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
GROUP BY h.hotel_id, h.hotel_name;
```

I'll let you construct the string.  The information seems more useful in separate columns.

Note the use of table aliases.  This makes the query easier to write and read.

Answer (score 3):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    h.hotel_id,
    h.hotel_name,
    COUNT(r.room_no) || ' total rooms ' 
        || SUM(CASE WHEN r.room_no > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        || ' have more than 2 bedrooms ' AS ACCOMODATION_AVAILABLE
FROM hotel h
INNER JOIN room r ON h.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
GROUP BY h.hotel_id, h.hotel_name;
```

Note: table aliases make the queries shorter and easier to understand. I modified your query to use them.